# How to add JAVA command line arguments in Eclipse Debug

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I am running the main function of class by running from command line the following:

```
java -classpath '/Library/apache-tomcat-7.0.62/lib/*:project/webapp/b2c/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/*' -Xmx3072m  -Xdebug com.myClass
```

I want to debug this class myClass.

But I cannnot do this while running from command line.

How can I debug myClass from eclipse using the same java -classpath variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right Click the class file -> Select "Debug As" -> Select "Arguments" Tab (provide the arguments)->Select "Apply" ->Select "Debug".

Right Click the class file -> Select "Debug As" -> Select "Classpath" Tab "Select BootStrap Entries"-> Add JARs "Provide jar file location"-> "Apply" ->Select "Debug".

Hope it helps.

Comment: @Saurabh did it help??

Comment: @Saurabh Did it help, If it does not please explain the issue you are facing. I will help.

Comment: No, I tried both: adding the classpath of the external jar and also added the java -classpath with the arguments as given int he question to the arguments tab.

Comment: Add classpath arguments in "classpath" tab.

Comment: Xmx will go in Arguments tab and classpath will go in classpath tab.

Comment: Thanks, I added the string as variable String to User Entries under Advanced option and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

When you try to run your class, you can edit the "Run Configurations..." and/or "Debug Configuration...", and you will have an argument tab in which you can set up the classpath